# reset form and errors when div is closed jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, reset

I have a popup div containing a form that when closed i would like the form to reset the errors and the fields within the form. I was planning on resetting the form in the disablePopup function. Other things to note is that it is a django project and i am using ajax to submit the form.

here is the code so far:

```
function disablePopup($contact_selector){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("fast");
        $contact_selector.fadeOut("fast");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}
```

so basically I would like to extend this code to allow me to reset a form within the contact_selector

any ideas would be much appreciated

thank you

katie

edit:
I think what is happening is that my django errorlist is appearing in the html and is separate from the form validation. What I would like to do is initialize a new form to my django project when i close the div - not just reset the form i have. that way when the open the form again the data is clean with no leftovers from their last entries

Comment: Few clarifying questions. Are you using this plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation ? resetForm() is called when "contact_selector" is clicked, is this wanted behavior? If so, why?

Comment: What is the exact question? How to reset form and errors?

Comment: @sergzach - yes sorry i would like to know how to reset errors and form

Comment: @lycha - i was using that plugin but i decided not to. Now instead I would like to know a way to reset my errors and form when the div is closed. sorry for any confusion

Comment: And what the problem with the existing code? Are you sure there are not mistakes? May be you have forgotten brackets in the line: "$contact_selector.fadeOut("fast");" before the $ sign and after *contact_selector*?

Comment: i have updated my question to be more precise as to what I am trying to accomplish - thank you

Comment: @katiebekell  you can take help from this links... [clearing form data](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/clearing-form-data) or [hot to reset a form](http://www.codigomanso.com/en/2008/12/resetear-un-formulario-con-jquery/) where you can specify the id and get the elements resetted

Comment: thank you swapnilsarewe this is helpful but it still only clears the form fields and not my errorlist. the errorlist is being generated by django. so i think this is more of a django issue then a jquery issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using the following code:

```
$("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){  
disablePopup($('.popup'));  
    var validator = $("#createrecipeform").validate();
    validator.resetForm();
    console.log(validator);
    $('#createrecipeform').each (function(){
  this.reset();
  });
    $('.errorlist').empty();
});
```